# Is it possible to run a .NET Core app as Windows Service AND Linux deamon

Tags: .net, windows-services, daemon, .net-core

Is it possible to, using the same code, create an .NET Core application that can be run as a windows service and as a deamon on linux?

Do you have an example/proof of concept?

Comment: Windows Service support is very weak currently and a lot of questions query about it. Linux Daemon Support (whatever that is) is in the targets of post .NET Core RTM (assuming in the next release).

Comment: You can definately do it. Both environment can hook up with command line tools based tools ... what .NET Core definately masters as of today..

Comment: Linux daemons can be written in nearly anything, since they're essentially just disconnected processes with no user interface. If you can do what you need in .Net core, you should be able to run it as a Linux daemon. However the real question is "Can you do what you want with .Net core at all?" since it's really pretty limited at this point.

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432031/asp-net-core-rc2-as-linux-deamon

Comment: RedHat: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/06/07/writing-a-linux-daemon-in-c/

Answer (score 4):

Linux daemon services can be in any language that could be executed on system.

Daemons can be executed using systemd (in Fedora: systemctl start name.service). To put your program on Linux Systemd services you should create a new .service file and move it into '/etc/systemd/system/'

The syntax of a service it is:

```
[Unit]
Description=The description of your service
After=previous services needed

[Service]
ExecStart=The program execution /sbin/helloworld.exe
ExecStop=The command given when killing the service

[Install]
WantedBy=services that needs your service
```

More information about Linux-Red Hat services and service modules: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html